# How to make a common id for more then one row

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have a table in my database  given like bellow

```
  Requestid(primary key,identity)  studentid   reqid
    1                                1          bc1
    2                                1          bc1
    3                                2          bc2
```

I  want to generate the same request id for student 1 if he is making more then one request.
I am using SQL server 2005 and Requested id is identity and student id will come when i submit my form but i want to generate reqid as automaticaly. It is same for the the student of same id and when next student submit it should change with the new id.

Plz hel me to solve it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want you could use a computed column to generate `reqid`.

```
create table StudentRequest
(
  Requestid int identity primary key,
  studentid int not null,
  reqid as 'bc'+cast(studentid as varchar(10))
)
```

Test:

```
insert into StudentRequest (studentid) values (1)
insert into StudentRequest (studentid) values (1)
insert into StudentRequest (studentid) values (2)

select *
from StudentRequest
```

Result:

```
Requestid   studentid   reqid
----------- ----------- ------------
1           1           bc1
2           1           bc1
3           2           bc2
```